# 10.10 Firefox Speed Problem

Tags: 10.10, networking, firefox, browser

Firefox Browser working very slow in my UBUNTU 10.10. I use Mobile to connect either via blue tooth or cable.

Is any tips to make it fast

Answer (score 2):

The speed issue might not be Firefox, but rather the connection speeds you're getting over your mobile tether.  There's no way to increase the speeds if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Disable ipv6:

- Type about:config in the address bar, press Enter.
- Find network.dns.disableIPv6 in the list.
- Right-click -> Toggle.
- Restart Firefox and try again.

See more common Firefox issues and solutions at http://www.webgapps.org/firefox/issues-and-solutions